# syncing SharePoint 2010 calendar to outlook 2013 and vice versa (can we also lock down a specific calendar to users?)

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-calendar

I can sync my calendar in sharepoint 2010 to outlook 2013.
But is this actually a 2 way sync i mean Sharepoint --> outlook and Outlook --> SharePoint?
Also i would like to have this calendar locked down to users which means they shouldn't be able to remove this specific calendar.
They have to view it by default

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean uncheck the calendar? In SharePoint or Outlook?

Comment: Colbs i have update the question.I wanted to say remove which means not delete but untick this specific calendar.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Synchronisation is certainly two-way, but I would advise you to [Use a Group Calendar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-group-calendar-HA101810606.aspx) in order to be enable resource management (availability of team members and conference rooms)

As far as the second question is concerned, I believe you need to look at Group Policies in your organisation. I don't think this can be controlled from SharePoint.